# c# WPF UI freeze after using MemoryStream

Tags: c#, kinect, freeze, memorystream

I have some trouble with this code:

```
private Bitmap WriteableBitmapToBitmap(WriteableBitmap wb)
{
     BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
     encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wb));
     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         encoder.Save(ms);
         Bitmap b = new Bitmap(ms);
         return b;
      }
}
```

If I start this code, the WPF UI freezes. I only want to convert a WriteableBitmap to a Bitmap so that I can use it for Emgu picture processing. The WriteableBitmap is created from Depthdata from the Kinect. I am new to programming so there is certainly a better way, but I hope this will work too.

Can anyone help me with that code?

Comment: If the UI is freezing it doesn't mean that the code is wrong, it means that you shouldn't be executing it in the UI thread; you should be doing the long running-UI work in a non-UI thread.  There are a million references as to how to offload work to a non-UI thread.

Comment: Freezing wouldn't be the typical outcome I'd expect.  The code is however certainly wrong, you cannot dispose the MemoryStream as long as the Bitmap object is life.  It needs to be able the access the stream later.  Remove the *using* statement.

Comment: Servy was right, it was a problem with the UI-thread, I solved it with an async solution and now it wortks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little bit late, but I would like to add some more information.

The problem is that you are using a synchronous call which uses the UI thread, unlike all other synchronous calls, this call takes some time, and therefore, your application is frozen until the call will finish.

You need to use an asynchronous call, so that your UI thread will be free, so the UI will not be frozen.

There are many ways to make an asynchronous calls, such as opening a new task, thread, or my preferable way, is to use the async await, which is very great - you can write a synchronous code, and to add async and await in the right places, and woops - it is an asynchronous code!

To read more about async await click [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx).